# Same Android APK for different Customers

Tags: android, apk

We are developing a Joomla school component and an associated android application. The purpose of this package is to sell to different schools. Joomla component will act as server and the android app is one of the client. When the android app launches it connects to the server gets the relevant themes and styles and loads the app.

The android app is developed as generic as possible so that each school can customise (at server) based on their needs.

The approach I am planning is as below.

1: My Developer build the APK file as mygeneric.apk
2: School A purchase the App from my website. I untar the APK change the icon, change the splash screen, change XML file (local settings) so that it can work for him.
3: Repack the APK and download to School A
4: School A uploads that into his google play store for their students, teachers and parents to download.

Note: The above approach (Step 2 and 3) will be automated via my website and no manual process involved

And similarly for School B, C etc...

Is it possible to upload same android APK file in different google accounts with different display names and icons.

Comment: yes it is possible but u need to keep all icon , themes ect on server and whenever xyz login in to app , ur smart app will chnage all things accordingly

Comment: when you sell app,sell it with a code,first time when user enters in the app then he/she have to enter code,store that code,cross check that code with server if exist then ok,else error popup. once get verified then removed that code from server so that client client resue that if he/she buy another copy of your app. i did the same in one of my app.

Comment: i dont think so its so easy to chnge app icon and name at run after you signed and released.because it a sealed copy when you try to chnge icon the you have to un sealed it,which is not feasible according to me.

Comment: I think the real problem is the package name. You can't upload something into googleplay twice using the same package name

Comment: Is it possible to change the package name (at step 2 in my approach).  Like editing the manifest file and then tar it. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Move your production builds to use [Gradle for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and set up a product flavor for each customer. You will be able to have different versions of the icon, and other stuff if needed (e.g., custom string resources with the customer's name), and Gradle can build custom APKs for each product flavor.